# Add featured image as post header background image

Tags: page-template

Wordpress Theme : **Twenty Twenty** [*provided by wordpress*]

Cloud Hosting : Digital Ocean

I need to put the featured image as post header background image.Please also explain that in which file of wordpress template, i need to update and how I can achieve this, I don't have prior wordpress development experience.

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress uses the single.php template for all the posts. Just navigate to your theme files and locate single.php under Wp-content/themes/twenty. There you can write your css to define a background image. That's it!

Good luck.